# Pushing a composite array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

Consider the following 'push' scenario.

```
(global) var refs = [] ;

var record = {id:1, references: ["12","145"]};
refs.push(record);
```

Nevertheless, when I debug with Chrome, the push function is skipped and the refs array is empty at the end. What is the reason?

EDIT:

The full code is something like this:

```
    gadgets.sciverse.makeRequest(entry['prism:url'], function(obj) {
        var testJson = $.xml2json(obj['text']);
        //  console.log(testJson);

        var tempArr = [];

        if (!testJson) {
            console.log('empty secondary response');
            return ;
        }

        var refSet = testJson ['item']['bibrecord']['tail']['bibliography']['reference'];

        if (!refSet)
            tempArr = [] ;
        else {
            $.each(refSet, function(i, e){
                tempArr.push(e['ref_info']['refd_itemidlist']['itemid']['text']);
            })
        }

        var verySillyTemp = {
            id: pid,
            arr: tempArr
        } ;

        refs.push( verySillyTemp );
    },params);

    console.log(refs);
```

Comment: It's not skipped: http://jsfiddle.net/sJYGr/

Comment: Can you post more of the code? Maybe something is happening later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `refs` is being set in an asynchronous call and you are logging it before it is set.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an alternative primitive operation over function calls in performance critical loops and functions.

You can use the following method.

```
record[record.length] = id;
```

It's just a dummy example, you can run the `for` loop through you record array.

Primitive operations can be faster than function calls.

Comment: Would speed matter for this particular problem? The push doesn't seem to be pushing. Not sure I see what this answer has to do with the stated problem. ???

Comment: This is just an alternative way of doing pushing.

Comment: This sounds like premature optimization, IMO. On the other hand, older browsers might not implement the push method so that is something to watch out for...

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error:

```
var record = {id:1, references: ["12","145"]};
```

Comment: sorry, i misspelled. id:1 is what i actually do.